# How to extract strings before and after a delimiter and store in mysql?

Tags: mysql, bash, awk, grep, cut

Want to insert into a mysql table with two columns a txt file with tons of lines containing the following structure:

```
random1:random2:random3:random4
random1:random2:random3:random4:random5
random1:random2
random1:random2:random3:random4:randomN
...
```

**Where the delimiter is ":"**

**And "random" represents a group of random characters.**

In the first column should be the string random1

In the second column should be stored the rest of the string random2:random3:random4:randomN

To extract the substring for the first column, already tried:

```
echo "random1:random2:random3:random4:randomN" | awk -F":" '{print (NF>1)? $1 : ""}'

echo "random1:random2:random3:random4:randomN" | sed 's/:.*//'

echo "random1:random2:random3:random4:randomN" | cut -d ":" -f1
```

How can I extract the substring from the first delimiter ":" until the end of the line and store it in the mysql table?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will change the first ":" into a "," to make a CSV file:

```
sed -E "s/([^:]*):/\1,/" myfile.txt > myfile.csv
```

Then you could import it into your table.

Or, you could create an SQL script:

```
sed -E "s/([^:]*):(.*)/insert into mytable (col1, col2) values ('\1','\2');/" myfile.txt > myfile.sql
```

then run it:

```
mysql -u root mydatabase -s < myfile.sql
```

Comment: Very nice try Bohemian but `echo "random1:random2:random3:random4" | sed -E "s/([^:]):(.*)/insert into mytable (col1, col2) values ('\1','\2');/"` returns randominsert into mytable (col1, col2) values ('1','random2:random3:random4');

Comment: We'd need to ensure that the "random" data doesn't include special characters like single quotes, commas, or backslashes. A line that contains a single quote character is going to give us a problem. (We do seem to be guaranteed that the "random" data doesn't include colon characters or newline characters... )

Comment: Note I omitted the `*` in my first version of the answer. Also, I haven’t texted this - I just thumbed it in on my phone. There may be some subtle changes you need to make to make it work, but the concept should work OK.

Comment: let's add this line to myfile.txt  `foo:hey'); drop table student; delete from account where 1=1 ; -- `  and see what happens...

Answer (score 3):

Here's a part of your solution (possibly):

```
while IFS=: read -r first rest; do
    do_something_with "$first" "$rest"
done < colon-separated-file.txt
```

Comment: I would imagine the rest of the solution would be to dynamically create an SQL script, so you only have to invoke mysql once.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can proceed as follows to split the string with the `:` separator :

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn, ':', 1), ':', -1) as random1,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn, ':', 2), ':', -1) as random1,
    ...
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn, ':', N), ':', -1) as random1,
FROM myTable;
```

Please note that this technique requires you to know in advance the maximum number of parts in the string.

Comment: The number of parts is also random, from 2 to N. I edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

If we are going to invoke MySQL to insert tons of rows into a table... assuming the "random" nature of random1, random2, random3 excludes a literal tab character `0x09`, `'\t'`...

I wouldn't muck with parsing the file in bash, that's a lot of overhead. I'd just execute the mysql client, and issue a MySQL `LOAD DATA` statement, and let MySQL read the file and parse it.

e.g.

assuming we want to insert rows to `mytable` columns `col1` and `col2`, something like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/foo.txt'
INTO mytable 
( @foo
)
SET col1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@foo,':',1)
  , col2 = IF(LOCATE(':',@foo)>0,SUBSTRING(@foo,LOCATE(':',@foo)+1,10000),'')
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

---

As a demonstration of the expressions used in the LOAD DATA statement:

```
SELECT t.foo
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.foo,':',1) AS foo1
     , IF(LOCATE(':',t.foo)>0,SUBSTRING(t.foo,LOCATE(':',t.foo)+1,10000),'') AS foo2
 FROM ( SELECT 'a' AS foo 
        UNION ALL SELECT ':b'
        UNION ALL SELECT '::c'
        UNION ALL SELECT ':::d'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'a:b'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'a:::d'        
        UNION ALL SELECT 'a:b:c'        
        UNION ALL SELECT 'a:b:c::e'
      )  t
```

returns

```
foo       foo1  foo2
--------  ----  -------
a         a     
:b              b
::c             :c
:::d            ::d
a:b       a     b
a:::d     a     ::d
a:b:c     a     b:c
a:b:c::e  a     b:c::e
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl also

```
$ cat carlos.txt
random1:random2:random3:random4
random1:random2:random3:random4:random5
random1:random2
random1:random2:random3:random4:randomN
$ perl -F: -lane ' print "insert into mytable (col1, col2) values (\x27",$F[0],"\x27,\x27",join(":",@F[1..$#F]),"\x27);" ' carlos.txt
insert into mytable (col1, col2) values ('random1','random2:random3:random4');
insert into mytable (col1, col2) values ('random1','random2:random3:random4:random5');
insert into mytable (col1, col2) values ('random1','random2');
insert into mytable (col1, col2) values ('random1','random2:random3:random4:randomN');
$
```